# Why sockets programming work when we use a reserved port?

Tags: java, sockets

Why when we use a reserved port in java socket its work on the localhost?

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(443);
```

This port from reserved ports (0~1023),but its work without any problem !!

Comment: They are "reserved" by the IANA in that they may define specific protocols for them. Therefore it is unwise to use such ports as they may conflict now or at a later time. But if you do use such a port the IANA police will not come to arrest you. On some operating systems e.g. Linux, ports below 1024 require elevated privileges.

Comment: Thank you i understood , but i want to ask when i use the 127.0.0.1 as a server and use 443 port in my code , is this port the actual port in my pc or it is a virtual port or something It has not relation ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use that port since that reserved port is not in use for any other purpose.

Comment: but i am using "localhost" (my pc) as a server and my pc use this port (443) for https I'm a little bit confused !